# long and int not enough and double wouldn't work

Tags: c++

I am using `C++` and I've heard and experienced that the maximum value that can be stored in a `int` 
and a `long` are same.

But my problem is that I need to store a number that exceed the maximum value 
of `long` variable. The size of `double` variable is pretty enough.

But the problem is using `double` variable
avoid me using the operator `%` which is necessary to code my function more easily  and some times there
seems to be no other ways than using it.

So please would you kindly tell me a way to achieve my target?

Comment: A signed 32 bit integer has the maximum value 2147483647. Is that not enough for you?

Comment: unsigned int or int64_t/uint64_t, if you must.

Comment: hey thank you very much .. that solved the problem what i just had to do was adding a int64_t type variable. and to do that i have to include the <stdint.h> header file.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the purpose. For a better answer, give us more context

Have a look at `(unsigned) long long` or [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: If the GMP library doesn't suit your licensing needs (not everyone can accept LGPL), there are plenty of other [arbitrary precision math libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Comment: problem is that long long is not support with the c++ language even though it is ok with c

Answer (score 3):

You can use type `long long int`or `unsigned long long int`

To know the maximum value that an untegral type can contain you can use the following construction as for example

```
std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
```

To use it you have to include header `<limits>`

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to compute the modulo of large integers. It's 99% likely you're doing encryption, which is hard stuff. Your question kind of implies that maybe you should look for some off-the-shelf solution for your top-level problem (the encryption).

Anyway, the standard answer is otherwise to use a library for large-precision integers, such as [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: There are many more uses for large numbers besides encryption! Also, the standard answer is `long long`, not GMP.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
    double max_uint = 4294967295.0;
    double max1 = max_uint + 2.0;
    double max2 = (max1 + 1.0) * (max_uint + 1.0);
    double f = fmod(max2,max1);

    return 0;
}
```

`max1` and `max2` are both over `unsigned int` limit, and `fmod` returns correct `max2 % max1` result, which is also over unsigned int limit: `f == max_uint + 1.0`.

**Edit:**

good hint from anatolyg: this method works only for integers up to 2^52. This is because mantissa of double has 52 bit, and every higher integer is representable only with precision loss. E.g. 2^80 could be == (2^80)+1 and == (2^80)+2 and so on. The higher the integers, the higher the inprecision, because densitiy of representable integers gets wider there.

But if you just need to have 20 extra bit compared to int with 32 bit, and have no other possibility to achieve this with an built-in integral type (with which the regular % will be faster I think), then you can use this...

Comment: This method works, but it silently loses precision for large values (above 2^52 or some such), which might be an unpleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

first there's a difference between int and long type

but for To fix the your problem you can use

unsigned long long int

Answer (score 0):

here is a list of some of the sizes you would expect in C++:

```
char      : 1 byte
short     : 2 bytes
int       : 4 bytes
long      : 4 bytes
long long : 8 bytes

float  : 4 bytes
double : 8 bytes
```

I think this clearly explains why you are experiencing difficulties and gives you a hint on how to solve them

Comment: You cannot compare integral types and floating point types over their bytes concerning storing integers: even a 4-bytes float can store much higher integers as a 8-byte long long...

Comment: I only added float and double as a reference; the answer actually refers ti the integral types

Comment: yes, and I was reminded that float can store higher integers then long long, but not at full precision. Only the mantissa size is deciding, so float provides 2.8 bytes and double 6.5 bytes (to stay in this comparison).